# Indexing and querying lists of UUIDs

Tags: performance, indexing, elasticsearch

Some fields in our data has lists of UUIDs as values.  E. g.:

```
{
 "name": "pupkin",
 "group": "admins",
 "assets": ["d1f84400-91b6-425c-a11b-9ba7e59930ce",
            "99478356-f6b3-49e2-8cae-f408d5a24492"],
 "action": "login",
 "children": ["2637833e-1017-4d82-bc65-951fffc09c7d",
              "c30f7c34-7a50-4031-bf74-94d413acec15",
              "cffef4ef-df9e-4079-ac2f-50bbe332e223"],
 "level": 20
}
```

Most of our queries for the data involve checking against long lists of UUIDs (dozens, sometimes hundreds, potentially thousands after we expand).  The lists change from time to time, so there is no way to precompute x∈L for x in all events for L in all lists as they are written.

Our current rather simple way of e. g. getting data for a histogram with  `_search?search_type=count` is:

```
 {"query":
  {"bool":
   {"must": [
    {"query_string": {"query": "user:pupkin AND (assets:d1f84400-91b6-425c-a11b-9ba7e59930ce OR assets:99478356-f6b3-49e2-8cae-f408d5a24492 OR assets:2637833e-1017-4d82-bc65-951fffc09c7d OR assets:c30f7c34-7a50-4031-bf74-94d413acec15)"}},
    {"range": {"time": {"gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z", "lte": "2014-11-01T00:20:00.0001Z"}}},
   ]}},
  "aggs": {"counts": {"date_histogram": {"field": "time", "interval": "minute", "min_doc_count": 0}}}}
```

But it is ineffective: a list of 60 UUIDs slows down the query by a factor of 10.  How can I reduce this factor?

Answer (score 1):

I would try, instead of `query_string`, filters only taking advantage of filters ability of being cached, thus making them faster upon subsequent requests:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "assets": [
                  "d1f84400-91b6-425c-a11b-9ba7e59930ce",
                  "99478356-f6b3-49e2-8cae-f408d5a24492",
                  "2637833e-1017-4d82-bc65-951fffc09c7d",
                  "c30f7c34-7a50-4031-bf74-94d413acec15"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "time": {
                  "gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "lte": "2014-11-01T00:20:00.0001Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "minute",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```